# How to manually override CSS @media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have made a mobile optimised style sheet for a site for a client using:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width : 768px)" href="css/mobile.css"  />
```

This works fine but they have requested a link that will show the site with its original, full page format.

Does anyone know a way to re-load the site and override the media query above? Is the only way to do this with JavaScript?

Comment: Either that or by having the server not output the mobile stylesheet at all when rendering the page, if the page is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would favour a solution whereby the stylesheet link is conditionally rendered via some logic in the code behind of the page which is triggered by a user selection. It's not as clean, but you could possibly achieve this by using some javascript too. Maybe along the lines of giving the stylesheet link an id:

`<link id="mobilestyles" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width : 768px)" href="css/mobile.css"  />`

Then calling a function to disable the stylesheet from a button event handler:

jQuery

```
$("#mobilestyles").remove();
```

Plain JS

```
document.mobilestyles[0].disabled = true;
```

You could then store the user's selection as a cookie and remember this for future visits.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using prop:   $('link[title=moboptcss]').prop('disabled',true); and attaching it to a click event

Comment: Good stuff :) glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

A link is only possible if you have access to the page rendering. I think using a plain link only, it is impossible.

But you can support [alternate styles](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/alternatives.html). This makes it possible the user can select in his browser the wanted layout.

Edit:
After "BoltClock" noticed that it may lacks on mobile browser support, you can do it anyway and choose the style by javascript. but that's near the answer by "Mel Lota"

Comment: Are there even any mobile browsers that let you choose from a set of alternate stylesheets?

Comment: hehe, you are right. this is about standards which are not used. i just tried chrome in my android phone. no support. but even on windows chrome i can't find buttons to change the style. in windows firefox (which i prefer to use) there is support for that. :,-(